# VirtualBox 64-bit host with a 64-bit guest switches to 32-bit VM's

Tags: virtualbox, 64-bit, virtualization, 32-bit

I have two 64-bit (hardware) machines.  On each one, I have a freshly installed, 64-bit VM running Ubuntu:

```
$ dpkg-query -W virtualbox 
virtualbox      6.0.6-dfsg-1
$ uname  -a
Linux zubu 5.0.0-13-generic #14-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 15 14:59:14 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Because this VM is the trial instance of what will be a fresh hardware-version Ubuntu host, I'm testing it for (among other things) VirtualBox.  So, this is an unusual place where I have:

```
- A base system (call it "host 0"), running VirtualBox, where:
- ...a guest host, call this "host 1", runs VirtualBox, where:
- ...another guest runs.  "host 2".
```

On "host 0", when we boot a fresh VM, 64-bit versions come up in the options list.

There, we build a successful 64-bit Ubuntu.  No issues that I'm aware of.  That's "host 1".  As far as I can tell, that VM comes up as a 64-bit instance.  In its "Settings..." window, under "System" -> "Acceleration", the "Enable VM-x/AMD-V" box is clicked "on", as per default.  In case it matters, "Enable Nested Paging" is also set at the default "on".

But, now when I run 'VirtualBox' within this VM, all of those settings appear as above, but when I try to create a VM from this process, only 32-bit options appear.  So:  A 64-bit (hardware) host runs a 64-bit (virtual) host, which "refuses" to configure a 64-bit guest.

I know this is an unusual layout and it's not something that makes sense long-term, but I'd like to be able to test my hardware on a VM before I run it for real.

Is there some switch I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VirtualBox does not support nested virtualization, in particular hardware acceleration for virtualization.

The result of this is that the L1 guest cannot run any VM with hardware acceleration, and can only run 32-bit unaccelerated VMs as 64-bit VMs require hardware acceleration.

If you need nested virtualization, consider using KVM with virt-manager in the host and also in the L1 guest. For bonus points, you can set up virt-manager on the host to connect to libvirt on the L1 guest via SSH, so that it can manage both VMs on the host and VMs in the L1 guest.